# Windows Remote Desktop and Narrator

Tags: windows, keyboard, remote-desktop

I have the exact same problem as outlined in [this](http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/list/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.windowsxp.work_remotely&tid=a46001b4-b556-4dd4-9acf-dda8c2e0fb73&cat=&lang=&cr=&sloc=&p=1) post.

> Everytime I start XP Remote Desktop,
>   Narrator and Utility Manager also
>   starts  and takes over the keyboard.
>
> When Narrator and Utility Manager
>   starts with Remote Desktop, "L" key
>   don't  work, the "u" key brings up
>   Utility Manager

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Ah, I think I may know the problem. The standard keyboard sequence for brining up the Utility Manager is `Windows Key` + `U`. I think my Remote Desktop Session was, for some reason, stuck thinking that I had the `Windows Key` held down. A quick press of `Windows Key` + `U` while in the logon dialog of my remote machine was enough to wake it out of its funk. This did, however, bring up the Utiliity Manager on the host, which I then simply dismissed and all was normal again.

If anyone has a more technical explanation of what was going on, I'd love to know.

Comment: I was running into this problem too. Your solution didn't work for me so I tried using the on-screen keyboard to enable/disable the Windows key and that appears to have worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Just double tap the Windows Key...that will make your keyboard "normal" again.

Comment: This worked for me, I am not sure if the key was stuck or it was because I was RDP'd into the machine, but it corrected it. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

I've done this many times, but had no idea how I'd accidentally activated it.

Now I know it's <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>.

If you press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>, you'll get a Utility Manager window pop up. in here one of the three options will say they are running. Select the option that is running and hit stop. This will then clear the Utility Manager.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the `utilman.exe` from running, change the permissions for `c:\windows\system32\utilman.exe`.

Right click *Properties → Security* tab, then go to *Authenticated Users → Read & Execute → deny*. Set *System → Read & Execute* to *deny* as well.

You can do the same for: `c:\windows\system32\narrator.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the connection with Remote Desktop, but I do know how to disable the Utility Manager:

1. Start the Microsoft Management Console (MMC) Services snap-in (Start, Programs, Administrative Tools, Services).
2. Right-click Utility Manager, and select Properties.
3. Set the Start-up type to Disabled, and click Apply. Then click OK.

To disable Windows Narrator:

Control Panel -> Ease of Access -> Ease of Access Center -> Explore all Settings -> Use the computer without a display. Uncheck the checkbox by `Turn on Narrator` and click Save.

Does that help?

Comment: Well, the connection with Remote Desktop is that this somehow got turned on and my login credentials contain the letter 'u' therefore I can't even login to the box because the utility manager keeps popping up.

Comment: @harrymc Now that I'm able to login to my box (see my "answer"), I'm going to try your suggestions. It seems like your answers must be for Vista because I'm on XP and I don't have "Ease of Access" under control panel and Utility Manager is not listed as a service. Through some quick googling, I've found that its simply an exe on XP and its called utilman.exe in your system32 folder. You can just rename it to disable the win+U shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Jason's solution worked for me in a different way.  It gave me a hint how to disable Narrator and Utility manager when we use remote desktop.  When you start Remote Desktop session, if the narrator or utility manager window pops up, close them with your mouse and then hit Windows Key + U (Utility Manager and Narrator Opens again), hit Windows Key + U once again and it will permanently disable the Narrator and Utility Manager and you can login successfully.  This worked for me.  Try it.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the user was hitting the X instead of logging off of a remote desktop connection, leaving the connection active but disconnected.  I went into Terminal Services Manager and reset the account.  This solved the problem.